# Перекодировка из cp1251 в utf-8 на Ruby

Tags: ruby, кодировка, перекодировка

Нужно привести крякозябры в удобочитаемый вид:

```
Ê¾ÓÙÕ‗Ý¹Ú Ë‗ÕÝ¯Û ´│õÔ│±ÝÞÚ ¯¸Þ¨¾ÔÓ¸ õÙ  ¾Ý│‗Óþ¾ ÐÔ│µ│±‗³ ´ÕÙ■±‗Û│Ô1 °‗.
```

Онлайн декодеры распознают это как cp1251 → cp850.

Пробовал варианты типа

```
string.force_encoding("cp1251").encode("utf-8") # и
string.force_encoding("cp850").encode("utf-8")
```

, но результата не добился.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Порядок обратный

```
string="Ê¾ÓÙÕ‗Ý¹Ú Ë‗ÕÝ¯Û ´│õÔ│±ÝÞÚ ¯¸Þ¨¾ÔÓ¸ õÙ  ¾Ý│‗Óþ¾ ÐÔ│µ│±‗³ ´ÕÙ■±‗Û│Ô1 °‗."
puts string.encode("cp850").force_encoding("windows-1251").encode("utf-8")
Туалетный Утенок підвісний очищувач дл  унітазу Свіжість пелюстків1 шт.
```