# Перекодировка из cp1251 в utf-8 на python3

Tags: python, перекодировка

[Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/411457/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-cp1251-%D0%B2-utf-8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-ruby) есть вариант на руби:

```
string="Ê¾ÓÙÕ‗Ý¹Ú Ë‗ÕÝ¯Û ´│õÔ│±ÝÞÚ ¯¸Þ¨¾ÔÓ¸ õÙ  ¾Ý│‗Óþ¾ ÐÔ│µ│±‗³ ´ÕÙ■±‗Û│Ô1 °‗."
puts string.encode("cp850").force_encoding("windows-1251").encode("utf-8")
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать это на python, желательно python3?

Comment: Если вдруг это строка из базы данных (mysql), то лучше нормально настроить параметры подключения к этой базе

Comment: А если это просто строка из соседнего вопроса, то лучше дайте ваши собственные строки, ибо ответ для вашей конкретной задачи может и не подойти

Comment: Строка:

x = 'Å«ñú«Ô«ó¬á ¬ ''Start'' ßÑÓóÑÓá ¿¡ÔÑúÓáµ¿¿. æÑÓóÑÓ ¿¡ÔÑúÓáµ¿¿ ß«í¿ÓáÑÔß´ óÙ»«½¡¿Ôý ñÑ®ßÔó¿Ñ. äÑ®ßÔó¿´ »«½ýº«óáÔÑ½´ ¡Ñ ÔÓÑíÒ¯Ôß´.'

На сколько я понимаю это cp850, вывести ее желательно в cp866 или cp1251.

Это строки системного лога windows, куда пишет приложение IBM, IIB. Только у него лог отображается "кроказябрами", остальные приложения информацию пишут корректно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> string = "Ê¾ÓÙÕ‗Ý¹Ú Ë‗ÕÝ¯Û ´│õÔ│±ÝÞÚ ¯¸Þ¨¾ÔÓ¸ õÙ ¾Ý│‗Óþ¾ ÐÔ│µ│±‗³ ´ÕÙ■±‗Û│Ô1 °‗."
>>> string.encode('cp850').decode('cp1251')
'Туалетный Утенок підвісний очищувач дл унітазу Свіжість пелюстків1 шт.'
```

UPD: для другой строки из комментария:

```
>>> x = 'Å«ñú«Ô«ó¬á ¬ Start ßÑÓóÑÓá ¿¡ÔÑúÓáµ¿¿. æÑÓóÑÓ ¿¡ÔÑúÓáµ¿¿ ß«í¿ÓáÑÔß´ óÙ»«½¡¿Ôý ñÑ®ßÔó¿Ñ. äÑ®ßÔó¿´ »«½ýº«óáÔÑ½´ ¡Ñ ÔÓÑíÒ¯Ôß´.' 
>>> x.encode('cp850').decode('cp866')
'Подготовка к Start сервера интеграции. Сервер интеграции собирается выполнить действие. Действия пользователя не требуются.'
```

Правда, возможно, лучше рассмотреть полный путь от получения строки до её использования (где, как и зачем) для более точного ответа

Comment: string1 = "Ê¾ÓÙÕ‗Ý¹Ú Ë‗ÕÝ¯Û ´│õÔ│±ÝÞÚ ¯¸Þ¨¾ÔÓ¸ õÙ ¾Ý│‗Óþ¾ ÐÔ│µ│±‗³ ´ÕÙ■±‗Û│Ô1 °‗."
print(string1.encode('cp850').decode('cp1251'))

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-8: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Если это в консоли Windows, то там принтить надо хитро и я уже так не умею

Comment: Спасибо. Через интерпретатор работает, но через консоль windows выходит ошибка, скрипт на руби при этом в консоль печатает нормально, вот пытаюсь разобраться как это работает в питоне.
А если выводить в файл то проблем не должно быть? Проблемы только с консолью?

Comment: На данный момент обсуждаю вопрос, если не получится настроить программу так что бы информация выводилась в другой кодировке, то буду писать скрипт, который будет брать информацию из лога и выводить в файл или консоль при этом перекодируя.

Comment: По идее только с консолью, да. В файл оно прекрасно запишется в кодировке utf-8 автоматически, а как в консоль WIndows правильно печатать, может кто-нибудь другой подскажет

Comment: @Kirode следует упомянуть что в реальных задачах вы должны исправить генерацию данных выше по течению, вместо попыток перекодирования позже. В частности, чтобы получить нормальный вывод в консоль (и вообще крайне рекомендуемая опция при работе с текстом) [следует использовать Unicode (избегайте байты напрямую в консоль выводить)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/229015/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-python-2-7)

Comment: @jfs если бы была возможность исправить проблему выше по течению, то так и сделали бы, но кодировка прописана в хардкоде, доступа к исходникам нету, поэтому приходится использовать костыли для нормального чтения логов. В любом случае, спасибо заинформацию.

Answer (score -1):

Если изменить кодировку консоли на cp866, то для вывода в консоль у меня сработал такой вариант:

```
print(user_input.encode('cp850').decode('cp866').encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
```

но вариант на руби работает без смены кодировки консоли, поэтому пытаюсь искать еще варианты.

Вариант на руби, работающий без смены кодировки:

```
puts string.encode("cp850").force_encoding("IBM866").encode("utf-8")
```